# Alternatives to plotly.graph_objects for plotting 2D lines (python or js)

Tags: javascript, python, plot, plotly, 2d

I am currently trying to plot lat long points with connected edges from a map api to a summarizing graph. I'm currently using plotly to do this from python, but my issue is that the horizontal axis 'zooms' or stretches, as documented [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/automatically-enable-panning-but-disable-zooming/9141) resulting in something like this: [image]

Can anyone recommend a 2D vector plotting library in js or python to accomplish this without stretching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have been quite abstract defining your data.  Hence I used simple to use **osmnx** which provides simple way to source nodes and edges
- edges will be *LineString*, **plotly** wants a list of lat and lon, hence extraction of co-ordinates and flattening
- have demonstrated

  1. line trace, clearly this is stretched (as expected) because it does not take into account geometric projections onto linear space
  2. line mapbox trace
  3. folium

#### source some points and connected edges

```
import osmnx as ox
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

# get some edges
gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf('Topsham, Devon')
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(gdf.loc[0,"geometry"], network_type='drive')
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
```

#### plotly lines

- these are stretched

```
# plotly lines are arrays of points with each line separated by None
px.line(
    x=np.concatenate(
        gdf_edges["geometry"].apply(lambda g: [c[1] for c in g.coords] + [None]).values
    ),
    y=np.concatenate(
        gdf_edges["geometry"].apply(lambda g: [c[0] for c in g.coords] + [None]).values
    ),
)
```

[image]

#### plotly mapbox

- no stretching

```
px.line_mapbox(
    lat=np.concatenate(
        gdf_edges["geometry"].apply(lambda g: [c[1] for c in g.coords] + [None]).values
    ),
    lon=np.concatenate(
        gdf_edges["geometry"].apply(lambda g: [c[0] for c in g.coords] + [None]).values
    ),
).update_layout(mapbox={"style":"carto-positron", "zoom":13})
```

[image]

#### folium (using geopandas)

```
gdf_edges.explore()
```

[image]

Comment: Can annotations be added for each subline and makrers for each point in the line_mapbox() figure?

Answer (score 1):

I used the NetworkX and matplotlib.pyplot library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).